# Background Image and Scroll bar

Tags: css, scrollbar, background-image

There is a page with background. Before was given as img:src. But I couldn't insert text on it. Because of this I changed that code as background-image. so far everything is ok.

Then the text I'll insert is long, it exceed height of background. I must add an scroll. I inserted max-height but confused here.

here the page is : http://www.heptasarim.com/test/cezayir2/menuler2.html

Background adress : /cezayir/images/menuorta.png

HTML:

```
 <div id="menuorta2">
        <p style="background-image:url(images/menuorta.png); background-repeat:no-repeat; width:812px; height:404px;" id="myazi">
        <span class="mbaslik">Kokteyl Prolonge Menü</span><br />
        <strong>menü:</strong><br />
        <strong>soğuk gezenler:</strong><br />
        biberli zeytin ve marine somon<br />
        tartolet içinde nar ekşili patlıcan salata<br />
        hindi füme badem turşu ve hardal<br />
        marine zeytin ve peynir şiş<br />
        <strong>sıcak gezenler:</strong><br />
        şişte ızgara limon ve kalamar<br />
        susamlı et<br />
        sigara böreği<br />
        <strong>sıcak büfe:</strong><br />
        dana külbastı<br />
        kuru erikli tavuk<br />
        patlıcan beğendi<br />
        pilav ve salata<br />
        <strong>tatlılar:</strong><br />
        bal kabaklı cheese cake<br />
        portakallı irmik helvası<br />
        </p>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
    #menuorta {
top:165px;
left:50px;
position:absolute;
z-index:0;
}
#menuorta2 {
top:127px;
left:20px;
position:absolute;
z-index:1;
}
#myazi {
color:#401c17;
font-weight:100;
font-family:Bookman Old Style;
font-size:13px;
padding:40px 65px;
max-height:200px;
overflow:hidden;
}
.mbaslik {
font-weight:bold;
font-size:16px;
}
```

**Fixed :**

```
background: url(../image/menuorta.png) no-repeat;
```

**..** and **/**

Thank you very very very much to everyone. Especially to @ferne97

Comment: So... what do you want to happen on your page? What is happening? *What have you tried?* Often experimentation or reading some online guides can fix a problem as well as we can, or better.

Comment: Thank you Math :) Now what do I want to happen ? I want to insert the text completely on background image. But the text is long :) That's why I want that a scroll bar appears. But as you see it doesn't. And background image remains at half.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set it to the width and height you want and add an `overflow-y: scoll;` to it.

```
#myazi {
    width: 600px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

If you want to the background larger than the scroll area, place another div inside like this..

```
<div id="myazi">
    <div class="inner-scroll">
        <!-- content here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Then in the css add this..

```
#myazi {
    background: url(path/image.png) no-repeat;
    width: 800px; /* width of actual image */
    height: 600px; /* height of actual image */
}

.inner-scroll {
    width: 600px; /* width of content area */
    height: 200px; /* height of content area */
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: Ferne this perfect. I am trying now. Wait :)

Comment: Ferne, the text is good now :) Scroll bar is very good now. But background image disappeared :( Please look up in the : http://www.heptasarim.com/test/cezayir2/menuler2.html

Comment: I think your path is wrong for the image file. Try changing the path to `background: url('../images/menuorta.png') no-repeat;`

Comment: Yes, I realized at the last moment :) Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove The following -

```
max-height :200px ;
```

This is setting the background image to 200px height .

And to improve the way your para is represented , you can utilize the css3 coloumn property to format it in better way . Scrolling is for me an unhealthy way to represent home page content.

Here's where you can see and learn to implement - http://www.quirksmode.org/css/multicolumn.html

Comment: Hey mate thank you very much. I'll try absolutely if my way won't work truely. By the way if I remove max-height and then text scrolling down sorely.

Comment: Css3 is the way to go .. the coding pattern you are using is way old. My suggestion would be to use html5 and css3 , and it will make your life much easier and the site will look more professional . Let me know if you need help .

Comment: Thank you mate. Please send me contact info. And let us follow in Twitter. @heptasarim (and later @gokaytemucin)